# could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: vue-awesome-swiper@4.1.1 npm ERR! Found: swiper@6.5.4 when run npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

i'm try to install a project on my pc but i got this error while runing npm install
it works fine on the old laptop but on the new i got this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vue-awesome-swiper@4.1.1
npm ERR! Found: swiper@6.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/swiper
npm ERR!   swiper@"^6.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer swiper@"^5.2.0" from vue-awesome-swiper@4.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-awesome-swiper
npm ERR!   vue-awesome-swiper@"^4.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: swiper@5.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/swiper
npm ERR!   peer swiper@"^5.2.0" from vue-awesome-swiper@4.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-awesome-swiper
npm ERR!     vue-awesome-swiper@"^4.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\mohammed mujahid\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohammed mujahid\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-28T08_40_24_210Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Make sure that it has the same node version

Comment: Are you sure that you need both `swiper` and `vue-awesome-swiper` installed?

Comment: i have the same node version but it still give me the same error

Comment: yes i wanna include both swiper ans vue-swiper

Comment: The error indicates that `swiper@5` is required, but you have a newer version installed. Try `npm i -S swiper@5`, and reinstall deps.

Comment: @Mina how to force using other node version ? its only work on latest version , for old version i have ever work , but now its not work . i use node 12 instead . today i have updated to 18 but there is have major change when change back i got the error .

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

The above comment will forcefully install all the packages

Comment: i did it but i got the same error again

Comment: Which version of node you are using?

Comment: Version 14.18.3

Comment: Try deleting `/node-modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file then try again with `--force`

Comment: still giving same error
this is included in the error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.3